# Bash/sh - difference between && and ;

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, multiplatform

I normally use `;` to combine more than one command in a line, but some people prefer `&&`. Is there any difference? For example, `cd ~; cd -` and `cd ~ && cd -` seems to make the same thing. What version is more portable, e.g. will be supported by a bash-subset like Android's shell or so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between double-ampersand (&&) and semicolon (;) in Linux Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669540/what-is-the-difference-between-double-ampersand-and-semicolon-in-linux)

Answer (score 275, accepted):

If previous command failed with `;` the second one will run.

But with `&&` the second one will not run.

This is a "lazy" logical "AND" operand between operations.

Comment: In other words it's got a short-circuit  behaviour

Comment: @peter Which one? The `;` one or the `&&` one? Or do you mean both?

Comment: @Shayan, the `&&`.

Comment: So you would prefer to run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and not `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade`, right?

Comment: For completeness, I'd mention also bash `cmd1 & cmd2`. It will run `cmd1` and `cmd2` simultaneously. (`cmd1 &` will launch task in the background, and `cmd2` will launch immediately)

Answer (score 76):

I'm using `&&` because a long time ago at the nearby computer:

```
root# pwd
/
root# cd /tnp/test; rm -rf *
cd: /tnp/test: No such file or directory
...
... and after a while ...
...   
^C
```

but not helped... ;)

`cd /tnp/test && rm -rf *` is safe... ;)

Comment: To be safer, I'd use `rm -rf /tnp/test`

Comment: To be even safer it is better to use `rm /tnp/test/ -rf` to prevent deadly enter missclick

Comment: ^C ^C ^\ ahaha that made me chuckle.

Answer (score 36):

In `cmd1 && cmd2`, `cmd2` is only executed if `cmd1` succeeds (returns 0).

In `cmd1 ; cmd2`, `cmd2` is executed in any case.

Both constructs are part of a POSIX-compliant shell.

Answer (score 19):

`&&` means to execute next command if the previous exited with status 0.
For the opposite, use `||` i.e. to be executed if previous command exits with a status not equal to 0 `;` executes always.

Very useful when you need to take a particular action depending on if the previous command finished OK or not.

Comment: Note that if you combine `&&` and `||`, then you must put the `&&` first. Otherwise, the `&&` executes if **either** the original or the `||` command succeeds (exits with 0 status).

Answer (score 10):

Commands separate by `;` are executed sequentially regardless of their completion status.

With `&&`, the second command is executed only if the first completes successfully (returns exit status of 0).

This is covered in the bash manpage under `Lists`.  I would expect any Unix-like shell to support both of these operators, but I don't know specifically about the Android shell.

Comment: Here's a link to the bash manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists

Answer (score 6):

`&&` allows for conditional execution while `;` always has the second command being executed.

In e.g. `command1 && command2`, `command2` will only execute when `command1` has terminated with `exit 0`, signalling all went well, while in `command1 ; command2` the second command will always be executed no matter what the result was of `command1`.

Answer (score 3):

&& is logical AND in bash.  Bash has short-circuit evaluation of logical AND. This idiom is a simpler way of expressing the following:

```
cmd1;rc=$?
if [ $rc -eq 0 ]; then
   cmd2
fi
```

Whereas the ; version is merely:

```
cmd1
cmd2
```