# What is the difference between && and ; in bash or command?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu

What is the difference between `&&` and `;` in bash or command?
Eg:

```
~$ echo one && echo two
```

And

```
~$ echo one ; echo two
```

Comment: See the [_Lists of Commands_ section in the Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) (have you even tried to read some documentation before asking?)

Comment: if we all had time to read references, there would stackoverflow.

Comment: This link may help as well, if you don't want to go to the official docs:  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/brian/entry/understanding_the_and_and_the_or_operators11?lang=en

Comment: In references you not only find the answer to your own questions but you also learn new things. So its always better to do your homework first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash/sh - difference between && and ;?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152659/bash-sh-difference-between-and)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf If everyone read the manuals before using something, stackoverflow would not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
~$ echo one && echo two
```

This runs the 2. command only if the first command succeeds.

```
~$ echo one ; echo two
```

This always runs the 2. command.

```
~$ echo one || echo two
```

This runs the 2. command only if the first command fails.

A command is considered successful if its [exit code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) is 0, and considered failed if
its exit code is != 0.