# Difference between && and `set -ex` in Dockerfiles

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

In Dockerfiles, I was used to seeing this pattern (also stated in [Docker's best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run)):

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

More recently, I'm quite often encountering a pattern like this:

```
RUN set -ex; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y curl; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I was wondering what the difference is. I've tried this:

```
$ (echo one; exit 0) && (echo two; exit 0)
one
two

$ (echo one; exit 1) && (echo two; exit 0)
one

$ (echo one; exit 1) ; (echo two; exit 0)
one
two

$ set -ex; (echo one; exit 1) ; (echo two; exit 0)
:bomb: boots me from the session :)
```

So there seems to be a difference but I'm not sure what it is and whether it's significant in the context of Dockerfiles.

Related (but not really answering this):

- [Bash/sh - difference between && and ;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152659/bash-sh-difference-between-and)
- [What is the difference between && and ; in bash or command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24367561/21728)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't specific to Docker; it's just regular shell syntax used in the `RUN` command. `set -e` causes the script to exit if any command fails, while `&&` only runs its right-hand command if the left-hand command does not fail. So in both

```
set -e
foo
bar
```

and

```
foo && bar
```

`bar` will only run if `foo` succeeds.

So, the two are identical *if* the entire script consists of a single list command `... && ... && ...` where a command only runs if every previous command succeeds. An example of how they would differ:

```
set -e
echo one
false
echo two
echo three
```

Here, `echo two` and `echo three` would never run. But in

```
echo one && false && echo two
echo three
```

the `echo three` would still run, because only `echo two` was "guarded" by the `&&` preceding it.

Comment: Thanks. Do you see any reason why one way or the other would be "better" in the context of Dockerfiles? I'm pretty sure some Dockerfiles I've seen have been rewritten from the && syntax to `set -ex`.