# What is the difference between double-ampersand (&&) and semicolon (;) in Linux Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

What is the difference between ampersand and semicolon in Linux [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29)?

For example,

```
$ command1 && command2
```

vs

```
$ command1; command2
```

Comment: I answered this here: http://superuser.com/a/619019/107862

Comment: Regarding the off-topicness, last time I checked, bash was still a programming language, but I was wrong before and it could be some dried fruit candy.

Comment: It is, and were you asking a question about a specific behavior or the right way to do a certain thing it would certainly be on topic. This falls into a greyer category of "question about the syntax of a language" which isn't as clearly a "programming" question as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: bash is in some ways dry, and in some ways sweet. At the end of the day it is quite pleasant and digestible. It cannot, however, be easily stolen from babies.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

The `&&` operator is a boolean AND operator: if the left side returns a non-zero exit status, the operator returns that status and does not evaluate the right side (it short-circuits), otherwise it evaluates the right side and returns its exit status.  This is commonly used to make sure that `command2` is only run if `command1` ran successfully.

The `;` token just separates commands, so it will run the second command regardless of whether or not the first one succeeds.

Comment: is the double ampersand `&&` different from a single ampersand `&` in bash?

Comment: @CharlieParker `&` causes the command to be run in the background, so yes.  "Run this in the background" is very different from "run this next command only if this other one succeeds."

Comment: The command2 will only run command1 returned *zero* exit status, meaning it finished successfully..

Comment: Does `;` still wait for the first command to finish?

Comment: @rfii Yes, but it executes the second command without regard for whether the first command succeeded. `a;b` means "run `a` and then run `b`."  `a&&b` means "run `a`, and then run `b` only if `a` was successful."

Answer (score 55):

### command1 && command2

`command1 && command2` executes `command2` if (and only if) `command1` execution ends up successfully.  In Unix jargon, that means *exit code* / *return code* equal to zero.

### command1; command2

`command1; command2` executes `command2` after executing `command1`, sequentially.  It does not matter whether the commands were successful or not.

Answer (score 11):

The former is a simple logic `AND` using short circuit evaluation, the latter simply delimits two commands.

What happens in real is that when the first program returns a nonzero exit code, the whole `AND` is evaluated to `FALSE` and the second command won't be executed. The later simply executes them both in order.

Answer (score 1):

`cmd1 ; cmd2`

... runs cmd1 then cmd2.

`cmd1 && cmd2`

... runs cmd2 if cmd1 exited with a code of zero.

Both yield a status code of the last executed command.

However, what other answers miss...

You might think that `cmd1 && cmd2` and `(cmd1 && cmd2)` are identical. In fact, they're very different. As is which command fails without the parens.

Consider the following. The status codes are determined by uncommenting `set -e`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e # exit on error
set -x

# false    # Yields status 1 and would cause the script to exit if -x is left uncommented

true && true     # Does not exit script! Good
echo A $?        # 0

false && true    # Does not exit script! Wut?
echo B $?        # 1

true && false    # Exits the script.  Wut? Wut?
echo C $?        # 1, if not -e

(false && true)  # Exits the script
echo D $?        # 1, if not -e

(true && false)  # Exits the script
echo E $?        # 1, if not -e
```

D and E make sense, and the difference with the others makes sense - parens creates a subshell. However that both of the following yield a status of 1, but that only the seconds exits the script is truly bizarre:

```
false && true  
true && false
```