# How can I run rails server with yarn start?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails

Is there a way for me to start my frontend on Reactjs when I start my server on Rails with a single command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'kill 0' INT
cd [path-to-rails-project] && rails s &
cd [path-to-react-project] && yarn start &
wait
```

This script should run both servers, and stop both servers when an interrupt is triggered (ctrl-c).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you mean making a script file and typing bash command? I don't preffer to make the file to root directory. Can I use that script as alias or something?

Comment: Yes, you would save this script to a file and execute it as a bash command. I modified the script so that you can store it anywhere in your filesystem.

Comment: Thank you! I got it using alias.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently package to achieve that, adding to you'r package something like:

```
"start": "concurrently \"bin/webpack-dev-server\" \"bin/rails s\""
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [Makefile](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/makefile/why_makefile.htm) or a [command-line alias](https://jonsuh.com/blog/bash-command-line-shortcuts/) that chains them together (e.g. `alias startall="rails s; yarn start"`). If they're in different directories it may be a bit more complicated, but you can [specify a path with yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49887269/5988852). Also worth noting the difference between `&&` and `;` in Bash which you can read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25669618/5988852).