# Open multiple projects in multiple windows in VScode CLI

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been searching for this, I usually work with multiple projects which are in different directories.

I have to use multiple(n) commands in terminal to open multiple(n) projects.

Example:

```bash
code project1
```

```bash
code project2
```

Is there any other way to open multiple projects in multiple VSCode windows using CLI other than command concatenation like `code project1 && code project2` ?

I tried with `code proejct1 project2` but VSCode is opening in a workspace.

Answer (score 0):

What you're getting from `code folderA folderB` is a [multi-root workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces). That's just how VS Code works when you do that. So no. If you want to open multiple folders each in their own VS Code instance, do multiple invocations of VS Code for each folder workspace you want to open. You can use whatever shell syntax is available for your shell to write those commands in a single line. Also, you probably want to read [What is the difference between double-ampersand (&&) and semicolon (;) in Linux Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25669540/11107541).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will wait to see if there is such a feature implemented. 
Yes, I'm aware of the difference between `&&` and `;`