# Permission error compiling Clozure CL despite sudo privileges

Tags: linux, permissions, makefile, common-lisp, ccl

I checked out Clozure Common Lisp 1.10 via subversion for my wheezy raspian raspberry pi. When I attempted to run armcl, I got the "GLIBC_2.15 not found" error. I used apt-get to install the latest version m4, 1.4.16-3. I followed Clozure's instructions to build the lisp kernel,
http://ccl.clozure.com/install.html

```
raspberrypi:/ccl/lisp-kernel/linuxarm$ sudo make clean && make
/bin/rm -f pmcl-kernel.o gc-common.o arm-gc.o bits.o  arm-exceptions.o image.o thread_manager.o lisp-debug.o memory.o unix-calls.o arm-asmutils.o  imports.o lispdcmd.o plprint.o plsym.o albt.o arm_print.o ../../armcl
/bin/rm -f pad.o  arm-spentry.o
m4 -DLINUX -DARM -I../ ../pad.s | as  -mfpu=vfp -march=armv6  -o pad.o
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create pad.o: Permission denied
make: *** [pad.o] Error 1
```

This permission error is unexpected since I have sudo privileges on this machine. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running `make clean` under `sudo`, but not `make`.  If you want to run both under `sudo` you must run:

```
$ sudo make clean && sudo make
```

(this is really a question about shell command syntax and has nothing to do with make).

Comment: Thanks, MadScientist! Once you pointed me to it being a shell command syntax issue, I found this post explaining exactly what "&&" means: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152659/bash-sh-difference-between-and