# How to switch back and forth between (general) pyenv python and system python in Ubuntu?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, pyenv

I used to work with python installed under `anaconda3` in my Ubuntu. But for some reason, I needed to also create a `pyenv` and generalize it for all users. To run python scripts, I learned that unlike `anaconda3`, I have to build `pyenv` with all the needed python packages as I was receiving errors saying that modules are not defined. For this reason, after installing `pyenv`, I installed required modules using `pip install <package_name>` in `(general) pyenv` shell. And now I am able to run the scripts. Is there a way to switch back and forth between `anaconda3` system python and `pyenv` python?

(just from the prompt *(general) username@username-Rev-1-0:~$,* I know that I am in `pyenv` right now.)

Here is the relevant portion of `.bashrc` file:

```
# added by Anaconda3 4.3.0 installer
export PATH="/home/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

# Load pyenv automatically by adding
# the following to ~/.bash_profile:

export PATH="/home/username/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Comment: I create aliases and added them to bashrc to switch between different Python installations on my system. For multiple virtual environments, there's virtual env manager.

Comment: Just added the content of that file. Could you give me an example of how to do that?

Comment: I added it as answer (to allow formatting). Check if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try adding this to your .bashrc.**

```
export ANACONDA_HOME="/home/username/anaconda3"
alias my_anaconda="unset PYENV_HOME && export PATH=$ANACONDA_HOME/bin:$PATH"

# Load pyenv automatically by adding
# the following to ~/.bash_profile:
export PYENV_HOME="/home/username/.pyenv/"
alias my_pyenv='unset ANACONDA_HOME && export PATH=$PYENV_HOME/bin:$PATH && eval "$(pyenv init -)" && eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"'
```

**On shell, try:**

$ my_anaconda

$ my_pyenv

Comment: The first one works and I can go back to anaconda system python but the second one gives me this error message:                                        No command 'pyenv' found, did you mean:
Command 'pyvenv' from package 'python3-venv' (universe)
Command 'p7env' from package 'libnss3-tools' (universe)
pyenv: command not found
No command 'pyenv' found, did you mean:
Command 'p7env' from package 'libnss3-tools' (universe)
Command 'pyvenv' from package 'python3-venv' (universe)
pyenv: command not found

Comment: Sorry, you meant to add that on top of what I already had. Right? In that case I am getting nothing after typing those commands (no error message though).

Comment: This is interesting. What is the meaning of &&?

Comment: && means 'lazy logical and'. command1 && command2 && command3 implies execute command1 then command2 (if command1 is successful) then command3 (if command3 is successful). You may find some more information at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152659/bash-sh-difference-between-and

Comment: not working for me. (Ubuntu 18.04 & bash)

Comment: When I tested it, I used Ubuntu 16.04. I do not know why it won't work on Ubuntu 18.04 but (I think it should) but I had not tested it against it.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by answers, thank you. I have used a similar approach on MacOs:

```
# in my ~/.bash_profile
# Anaconda app is installed and initiated at the terminal start
# path to Anaconda: /Users/<USER>/opt/anaconda3/


switch_pyenv(){
    conda deactivate
    conda deactivate # in case you're not in base env
    eval "$(pyenv init -)"
    eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
}

switch_conda(){
    conda activate base
    export PATH="/Users/<USER>/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
}


# quick check which python, pip
w(){
  which python
  which pip
  py -V
}
```

When I switch to an environment, I check 'where am i' with the shorthand `w`.

Comment: this works in bash, but not when I enter a tmux session. I get the error `_pyenv_virtualenv_hook: command not found` when trying to switch back and forth

Comment: Hi, did you try reloading your Bash?
````
$ exec Bash
````
or  ``` source . ~/.bashrc ```

Comment: just tried it, problem remains unfortunately

Comment: sorry, no solution I could think of.