# How to use pyenv like conda?

Tags: conda, tmux, miniconda, pyenv, python-poetry

I'm currently using both pyenv and conda.
With pyenv I keep creating local python environment in individual folders using poetry.
With conda (acutally miniconda) I use different python environments across folders.

Since it's very annoying to always switch between both ([especially when trying to use it from within tmux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67436322/how-to-switch-back-and-forth-between-pyenv-python-and-system-python-in-tmux)), my question is if I can use pyenv in the same way as conda? Meaning I'd like to activate specific named environments and use them across folders?

Answer (score 0):

turns out pyenv has it's own virtualenv. Here is an example how to create a python 3.8.5 environment and activate it in the current shell

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.8.5 py38_venv
pyenv activate py38_venv
```

One can also `pip install` arbitrary python packages into that virtual environment